# How to get sms records by subaccount

Tags: c#, sms, twilio

I know about using the class MessageListRequest to ask for a list of SMS messages from the Twilio server.  There is no Subaccount filter as a parameter when defining the request.  Does anyone know how to get the message list for only those messages associated with a specific subaccount?  Thanks.

I have used the subaccount credentials to get the list of messages but the result of the Twilio request is a list object with zero entries .  I know there are messages in the sub account because I can see them in the Twilio dashboard for the subaccount.  Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong in this code?

```
    var aRequest = new MessageListRequest();
        aRequest.From = null;
        aRequest.To = null;            
        aRequest.DateSent = null;

         GetSubAccounts();
         if (mySubAccountSid != null)
         {
             TwilioRestClient aTwilio = new TwilioRestClient(mySubAccountSid,
                                        mySubAccountToken);
             var aResult = aTwilio.ListMessages(aRequest);
             if (aResult != null)
             {
                 foreach (var aMessage in aResult.Messages)
                 {
                     mySQLManager.UpdateSMSLogTable(aMessage, myVesselID);
                     Methods.WriteLog(aMessage.Sid + " " + aMessage.To + " " + aMessage.Body);
                 }
             }
             return aList;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The simple way, which is likely what you mean, is even if you use
   your master credentials for auth, but a subaccount SID in the URL
   provided for [Message List Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list),
   `/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages`, you get the resources
   for that subaccount.

   The C# library has a [`GetAccount`](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/wiki/Twilio.Api#account-getaccount-accountsid) method that takes an account
   SID and returns the Account object (representing the subaccount) for
   which you should then be able to make API calls as normal.

   ```
   var account = twilio.GetAccount("SUBACCOUNT_SID");
   ```
2. Eventually if you want to track things in a more sophisticated
   manner, you may decide to use [UsageRecords](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/usage-records).

   Using `UsageRecords` combined with [Subaccounts](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/subaccounts) will allow you
   to build usage reports and set triggers based upon some behavior.

   The two links provided above will show you how to work with each in
   more detail but an example of grabbing a list of all-time usage for
   sms would like this in C#:

   ```
   // Download the twilio-csharp library from twilio.com/docs/csharp/install
   using System;
   using Twilio;
   class Example 
   {
     static void Main(string[] args) 
     {
       // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
       string AccountSid = "ACCOUNT_SID";
       string AuthToken = "AUTH_TOKEN";
       var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

       var records = twilio.ListUsage("sms", null, null, null, null, null);

       foreach (var record in records.UsageRecords)
       {
         Console.WriteLine(record.Count);
       }
     }
   }
   ```